# tumblr - How can I make a div appear based on the height of a certain post's caption?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am editing my theme on tumblr and trying to use jquery to make it so that a certain div only appears if the height of a text post or a post's caption is over 250px. It is pretty simple and seems to be working, but only seems to take in the first post and then sets the div visible for all the other entries too. Does anyone know how I can adjust the code so that each post goes through the code instead of it being set for the first post only?

note: #entry is the ID that's being used for styling the posts. .caption is the caption's class and .b is the div I want shown only if the caption is over a certain height.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#entry .caption").height()>250) {
      $("#entry .b").show();
    }
  });
```

Please let me know if you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change the

```
if ($("#entry .caption").height()>250)
```

to:

```
if ($("#entry .caption").height()>=250)
```

so you also match `250px` of height and above.

And for each element that matches:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.entry .caption').each(function(i, ui){
        if ($(this).height()>=250) {
            $(this).parents('.entry').find('.b').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks! but no, it's not that -- it's that the code is only taking in the first post that loads and using it to set the div visible for all the other posts regardless of their heights. I'm make it so that every post passes through the code individually and can't get anything to work...

Comment: Then you should not use `id` , because it is only capable of reading one element, use class instead like `entry` and also change the HTML.

Comment: Still does not seem to be working. I think there might not be a way to check every individual post's height on tumblr since they all have to use one class or id.